# setTimeout returns error with Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in AudioContext in Chrome

Tags: javascript, audiocontext

In Chrome I first create a continuous tone with the AudioContext:

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);

var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

oscillator.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

oscillator.start();
```

Now I want to stop it after a few milliseconds. So I do this:

```
setTimeout(oscillator.stop, 500)
```

This returns the error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

However if I do;

```
setTimeout(function(){oscillator.stop()}, 500)
```

it works fine.

I would like to now why the first one doesn't work and returns an error. It seems like the straightforward way to do this.

Comment: `setTimeout(oscillator.stop.bind(oscillator), 500)`

Comment: Thanks, that works. But why does it work, and why doesn't the simple way work?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but another way to achieve the same effect would be to call `stop()` directly with the number of seconds to wait as the parameter so in your case `oscillator.stop(0.5)`. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uv5e8to5/)

Comment: I tried that first actually but it seems to be buggy in Chrome. It seems to measure the time since AudioContext was created, rather than the time since it was called.

E.g. this: https://jsfiddle.net/j3q3npkc/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original code doesn't work because the `stop` function is passed to `setTimeout` without any context - it does not know which object it is supposed to act on.  If you *invoke* it like this:

```
oscillator.stop();
```

Then within `stop`, the special variable `this` is set to the object pointed to by `oscillator`.  But if you refer to it like this:

```
var x = oscillator.stop;
```

The function is not actually invoked.  Rather, a reference to the function is simply extracted from `oscillator` and stored elsewhere.  The function does not remember where it came from, and could be stored in many different variables or object properties at the same time.  For example:

```
var x = {};
x.foo = oscillator.stop;
x.foo();
```

The last line calls `stop` with a context of `x` (`this` is set to `x`) rather than `oscillator`.  (The function's body will cause errors since `stop` makes assumptions about what its context looks like, but the call itself is legal.)  Alternatively, if you do this:

```
var foo = oscillator.stop;
foo();
```

Then `stop` will be called with only a default context.  In strict mode, `this` will be set to `undefined`, and in non-strict mode, `this` will be set to `window`.

When you do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){oscillator.stop()}, 500)
```

The anonymous function invokes `stop` with the proper context.  If, as suggested by @elclanrs in comments, you do this:

```
setTimeout(oscillator.stop.bind(oscillator), 500)
```

It is effectively the same thing: an anonymous function is created that calls `stop` with a context of `oscillator`.

Comment: Thank you for writing such a good answer to what I now realize was a stupid question. It seems so clear to me now after reading your answer, but when I wrote it I was extremely confused.

Comment: @Houshalter Your question is completely valid!  These things aren't explained by base JS knowledge and there's nothing in most documentation that implies that the caller of the function must be the original object.  Great explaination, +1!